# WCF: Configuring Known Types

Tags: wcf, wcf-configuration

I want to know as to how to configure known types in WCF. For example, I have a **Person** class and an **Employee** class. The **Employee** class is a sublass of the **Person** class. Both class are marked with a `[DataContract]` attribute.

I dont want to hardcode the known type of a class, like putting a `[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Employee))]` at the Person class so that WCF will know that Employee is a subclass of Person.

Now, I added to the host's App.config the following XML configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.runtime.serialization>
    <dataContractSerializer>
      <declaredTypes>
        <add type="Person, WCFWithNoLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=null">
          <knownType type="Employee, WCFWithNoLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
        </add>
      </declaredTypes>
    </dataContractSerializer>
  </system.runtime.serialization>
  <system.serviceModel>
    ....... 
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I compiled it, run the host, added a service reference at the client and added some code and run the client. But an error occured:

> The formatter threw an exception while
>   trying to deserialize the message:
>   There was an error while trying to
>   deserialize parameter
>   `http://www.herbertsabanal.net:person`.
>   The InnerException message was 'Error
>   in line 1 position 247. Element
>   `'http://www.herbertsabanal.net:person'`
>   contains data of the
>   `'http://www.herbertsabanal.net/Data:Employee'`
>   data contract. The deserializer has no
>   knowledge of any type that maps to
>   this contract. Add the type
>   corresponding to 'Employee' to the
>   list of known types - for example, by
>   using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute
>   or by adding it to the list of known
>   types passed to
>   DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see
>   InnerException for more details.

Below are the data contracts:

```
[DataContract(Namespace="http://www.herbertsabanal.net/Data", Name="Person")]
    class Person
    {
        string _name;
        int _age;

        [DataMember(Name="Name", Order=0)]
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }

        [DataMember(Name="Age", Order=1)]
        public int Age
        {
            get { return _age; }
            set { _age = value; }
        }
    }


[DataContract(Namespace="http://www.herbertsabanal.net/Data", Name="Employee")]
    class Employee : Person
    {
        string _id;

        [DataMember]
        public string ID
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }
    }
```

Btw, I didn't use class libraries (WCF class libraries or non-WCF class libraries) for my service. I just plain coded it in the host project.

I guess there must be a problem at the config file (please see config file above). Or I must be missing something. Any help would be pretty much appreciated.

Comment: i suspect that the configuration works only if using a third-party library, referencing it to the service. i'll try it and i'll get back to this question if i find some answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess I have found the answer now.

The configuration file I posted above looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.runtime.serialization>
    <dataContractSerializer>
      <declaredTypes>
        <add type="Person, WCFWithNoLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=null">
          <knownType type="Employee, WCFWithNoLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
        </add>
      </declaredTypes>
    </dataContractSerializer>
  </system.runtime.serialization>
  <system.serviceModel>
    ....... 
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

What I just added was, the Namespace of the **Person** class and the **Employee** class. And no need for the longer Version and Culture values.... The correct configuration should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.runtime.serialization>
    <dataContractSerializer>
      <declaredTypes>
        <add type="WCFWithNoLibrary.Person, WCFWithNoLibrary">
          <knownType type="WCFWithNoLibrary.Employee, WCFWithNoLibrary" />
        </add>
      </declaredTypes>
    </dataContractSerializer>
  </system.runtime.serialization>
  <system.serviceModel>
    ....... 
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Now it is shorter and makes more sense. But if 3rd party libraries are used, then adding version, culture, publickeytokens would be required.

Comment: Upvote.  Did you have to do anything on the Client side .config ?

Comment: You will need to duplicate the configuration on the client so it can receive the new type.

Answer (score 6):

I know this was answered a long time ago, but, another (maybe more obvious for future programmers) solution:

```
[KnownType(typeof(SubClass))]
public class BaseClass
```

Scott

Comment: this is not always possible if the subtype is in a different project

Answer (score 0):

I got this lengthy error message also in another case. I did use the `KnownTypeAttribute` and had successfully deployed an application which uses `WCF.RIA` to production. In the second release I added a new subtype, and added the necessary corresponding `KnownTypeAttribute` (the compiler did not accept it without this attribute - great). What the compiler did accept and what ran on my machine, did not run in production, however. Only in production I got the error mentioned above. Comparing all the uses of the existing subtypes and the new one revealed I had forgotten that `WCF.RIA` requires the name of the subtype to be used in a name of a method, like GetMySubTypes. So if you get this error after having added the attributes, see whether it's because of `WCF.RIA`s conventions.