# WCF passing collection of multiple types

Tags: wcf

Should there be any problem passing this kind of a collection in WCF?

```
class Parent
{
  [DataMember]
  // some data members

  [DataMember]
  Child myChild;    
}

class Child : Parent
{
  [DataMember]     
  // some more data members

  [DataMember]
  Parent myParent;
}
```

Should there be any problem passing a list of `Parent`?

I get strange results, sometimes the channel faults, sometimes it doesn't fault but gives me no data until I remove all the children from the list.

Comment: updated my answer with the CollectionDataContract - check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to put the `[DataContract]` on every class that you want to have serialized and deserialized by WCF - it is **not** automatically inherited!

```
[DataContract]
class Parent
{
   .....
}

[DataContract]
class Child : Parent
{
   .....
}
```

If you're dealing with collections of things, then you might need to check into the `CollectionDataContract` :

```
[CollectionDataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Parent))]
[KnownType(typeof(Child))]
public class CustomCollection : List<Parent>
{
}
```

Also, WCF and SOA in general are quite a bit different from OOP and don't handle inheritance all that well. You will most likely have to put `[ServiceKnownTypes]` or `[KnownType]` attributes on your service contracts in places where you want to use and support polymorphism.

So if you have a service method that accepts a `Parent`, but should also be able to accept a `Child` instance as well, then you need to decorate the method with the `[KnownType]` attribute to make this information available to WCF.

See the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx) on the KnownType attribute, or check out this other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560218/wcf-configuring-known-types) on the topic.

Marc

Comment: It seems that you are right.. but, although I've added all the right attributes I still get some strange behavior.
I think it's involves the face that the object are being created by NHibernate, and maybe the problem is there somewhere...

Comment: Dani, now you mention, that you use NHibernate 
As far as I remember it uses classes with protected setters, am I right?
While WCF requires that all the properties marked with DataContract attribute have public getter and setter

Comment: Hi, WCF is fine with the NH properties, 
While still investigating, I've found the problem was that I used a criteria typeof(father) to get the objects, and NH returned all the father and sons (as expected...) and WCF couldn't handle it - b/c it expected only objects of type parent (although containing the child object inside was not a problem - having both parent and child on the array returned faulted the channel.
Now I'm checking if I can change the query to get only "Father" objects and it should resolve the issue, I hope.

Comment: Marc, it looks like another problem might be masking this issue. There is a circulare reference issue here, the parent points the child that points the parent. NH is ok with this, but WCF is not. 
I have another Q. about this here, and I'm still investigating many solutions for this problem, once the circular reference will be resolve, I can get back to the inheritance issue...

Comment: resolved the circular reference issue, I'll add back the inheritance issue and run a test with your solution to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding IsReference and KnownType to your classes, like shown below:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
[KnownType(typeof(Child))]
class Parent
{
  [DataMember]
  some data members

  [DataMember]
  Child myChild;
}

[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
class Child : Parent
{
  [DataMember]
  some more data members

  [DataMember]
  Parent myParent;
}
```

Comment: Tried it, and also killed the inheritance, but it still doesn't work 
(now the father only has a IList of it's children but the child object doesn't inherit the father
(they both inherit some base class)

Comment: For collection of generic objects that work through WCF read here: http://borismod.blogspot.com/2009/06/v2-wcf-collectiondatacontract-and.html