# WCF + Silverlight 4: How to configure known types via Web.config?

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight-4.0

I want to know if it is possible to configure known types the way described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560218/wcf-configuring-known-types/560298#560298) when we are using a Silverlight 4 client?

Only thing that seems to work is using the `KnownType` attribute, and we'd like to avoid that solution since the classes are in different assemblies and we don't want dependencies between them.

Here's a sample of the configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <!-- *snip* -->
  <system.runtime.serialization>
    <dataContractSerializer>
      <declaredTypes>
        <add type="Foo.Dto.FooDto, Foo.Dto, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
          <knownType type="Foo.Dto.BarDto, Foo.Dto, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
          <knownType type="Foo.Dto.BizDto, Foo.Dto, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
        </add>
      </declaredTypes>
    </dataContractSerializer>
  </system.runtime.serialization>
  <!-- *snip* -->
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx) on the topic - basically, this is what you need:

```
<configuration>
   <system.runtime.serialization>
       <dataContractSerializer>
           <declaredTypes>
             <add type="MyCompany.Library.Shape, MyAssembly, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXX, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
                 <knownType type="MyCompany.Library.Circle, MyAssembly, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXX, processorArchitecture=MSIL"/>
             </add>
           </declaredTypes>
       </dataContractSerializer>
   </system.runtime.serialization>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I might be doing something wrong, but I just cannot get the known types specified in a configuration file. Configuring them that way always results in error in the Silverlight end.

Comment: @chlb: can you **show us** your config file?? Please update your original question by editing it... thanks!

Comment: I've edited my question to include a sample of the configuration.

Comment: We took another tackle at this issue and eventually found out that the Reference.cs file generated by Microsoft.Silverlight.ServiceReference does not include the known type configuration for some reason. I'll mark your answer as the correct one since that is how the config file should look.