# how to convert value of a string to type

Tags: c#, type-conversion

As WCF does not support Types, I'm passing the type as a string type. For eg:

```
var str= "int"
```

Now I want to convert this to a Type **int** as i want to pass CLR types as parameters.

Is there anyway of achieving this?

Comment: Conversion of the value to the Type from value "int" to type int

Comment: WCF does support types you just have to learn how to use it.

Comment: @Shadow well so tell me how ?

Comment: You have good example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560218/wcf-configuring-known-types).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean like using [Type.GetType()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx)?

```
string typeName = "System.Int32"; // Sadly this won't work with just "int"
Type actualType = Type.GetType(typeName);
```

Comment: @Rwaling well this is one working way but anyway round with just passing int rather than the whole "system.Int32"

Comment: @Ankit - there are only a limited numer of aliases like this (`int`, `long`, `byte`, `float`, `double`, `decimal`, probably a few more). You could easily set up a `switch` statement to catch all of these, and then use `GetType` to handle real type names.

Comment: Thought of it but was just looking for an alternate option. Thnx :)

Answer (score 2):

If the type is in the currently executing assembly or in Mscorlib.dll, it is sufficient to get the type name qualified by its namespace (see [@Rawling answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11559091/63011)):

```
var str = typeof(int).FullName;
// str == "System.Int32"
```

Otherwise, you need an assembly-qualified name of the `Type`:

```
var str = typeof(int).AssemblyQualifiedName;
// str == "System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
```

Then you can use [`Type.GetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx):

```
var intType = Type.GetType(str);
```

---

**Edit:**

If you want to use the system aliases, you can create a `Dictionary<string, Type>` to map all of the aliases to their type:

```
static readonly Dictionary<string, Type> Aliases =
    new Dictionary<string, Type>()
{
    { "byte", typeof(byte) },
    { "sbyte", typeof(sbyte) },
    { "short", typeof(short) },
    { "ushort", typeof(ushort) },
    { "int", typeof(int) },
    { "uint", typeof(uint) },
    { "long", typeof(long) },
    { "ulong", typeof(ulong) },
    { "float", typeof(float) },
    { "double", typeof(double) },
    { "decimal", typeof(decimal) },
    { "object", typeof(object) }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 int myInt = 0;
    int.TryParse(str, out myInt);

    if(myInt > 0)
    {
     // do your stuff here
    }
```

---

if you mean you only want to sent the type then use

`string str = myInt.GetType().ToString();` 
and it will give you the type